# Matlab plot without complete matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have a problem with Matlab plot. 
I have an matrix with 11 arrays of values. The values in the array are imported values from an audio tool. In this case Distortion. The point is that not all arrays in the matrix are the same length.
What happens is that the plot function fills all empty values with zeros (see figure).
How can I force Matlab to leave this values empty so that the line stops?

The plot:

[image: Screenshot]

I have Matlab 2012b and this is the code as it is now:

```
a = dlmread('/Distortion_8_2.txt', '\t');
[m,n] = size(a)
f_dist = a(:,1); a = a(:,2:n); 
figure
semilogx(f_dist,a)
```

Comment: One thing I could suggest is to use a `for` loop in conjunction with `hold on`.  That way you can loop through each set of values and plot only up to where the last non-zero value is.  Is there more information you can give me regarding how many elements are in each array?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to truncate your plot so that it only shows the points in all of the plots where there is no zero flatlining?

Comment: I think `dlmread` is at fault here to introduce zeros. I think one  solution would be to make those zeros as NaNs. So, after you have `a = a(:,2:n);`, do this - `a(a==0)=NaN` and then plot.

Comment: @Divakar: Wow nice.  I didn't know you could introduce NaN's and it won't plot on the screen.  +1.